# Number of points on the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 - x$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I need to know the value of $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} \chi(x^3 - x)$, where $q = p^r$ with $p$ prime and $\chi$ is the Jacobi symbol.

If we take $-x$, we have $\chi((-x)^3 - (-x)) = \chi(-1)\chi(x^3 - x)$ and $\chi(-1) = -1$ since $q \equiv 3 \; (mod \; 4)$. Thus, the terms for $x$ and the terms for $-x$ cancel. Therefore, $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} \chi(x^3 - x) = 0$.

But, if $q$ is even or  $q \equiv 1 \; (mod \; 4)$, then $\chi(-1) = 1$.

How can I find the value of $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} \chi(x^3 - x)$ when $q$ is even or  $q \equiv 1 \; (mod \; 4)$?

Comment: "$\chi(-1)=-1$ since $x\equiv 3\pmod{4}$"?  Anyway, if $q$ is even, every element is a square (Frobenius).

Comment: The case of an even $q$ is not interesting, because you don't have an elliptic curve in that case. And, as @user10354138 explained, every element of the field has a unique square root, so the number of points is equal to $q+1$. The observations we can immediately make are A) the Hasse-Weil bound, B) the cubic splits modulo any prime so the elliptic curve has full 2-torsion, and hence the number of points is a multiple of four.

Comment: We also have the Hasse-Davenport relation (explaining how the zeros of the $L$-function behave under extensions of scalars). Implying that it suffices to handle the prime fields. We quickly see that with $p=13,17,29,37$ we have $8,16,40,40$ points respectively. I don't see a pattern. If you can find the rank of the rational variant (surely done in LMFDB), then there may be a tendency related to B-SD conjecture. But that's above my paygrade.

Comment: So if $q=p^n$, $p\equiv-1\pmod4$, $n$ even, then the symmetry you used and Hasse-Davenport settle the matter.

Comment: For $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, write $p=\pi\overline{\pi}$ in ${\bf Z}[i]$.  Precisely one of $\pm\pi,\pm i\pi$ is congruent to $1\pmod{2+2i}$. Call that one $\pi$ again. Then $\sum_{x\in{\bf F}_p}\chi(x^3-x)$
equal to $-\pi-\overline{\pi}$.

Comment: @ReneSchoof Wow! Why are the zeros of the $\zeta$-function of this curve in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$? Is that some CM argument?

Comment: In general $E(\mathbb{F}_{p^r}) = p^r +1 - \alpha^r - \beta^r$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the minimal polynomial of the $p$-power Frobenius endomorphism, which is of the form $T^2 - a T + p$ for some $a$ (the trace of Frobenius). Since $E$ has CM, this trace is related to the trace of the Hecke character of the CM field, as described for instance in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2715349/). Hopefully someone more familiar with CM can connect the dots!

Comment: This is actually done in Ireland and Rosen's *Classical Introduction to Number Theory*, Ch. 18, $\S4$, Theorem $5$ (p. 307), just using Jacobi sums and reciprocity.